# WMI throwing Exception "Invalid Query" on second attempt to query the same server

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a following code, almost all the time this code works for most of my server, but for some specific servers, it just fails on second part of query. this code query the SQL Server Service First and in second part it queries the SQL Sevrer Agent Service.

I have tried all possible combination of creating another Scope and Query Object, but somehow the server I am trying to query does not return seccond part, looks like after the scope is connected and first query is executed, second part is blocked by something on server..! Any help on this one is appreciated.. almost 99% of servers works fine and returns desire results, but just 2 or 3 servers fails for second part..

If this is WMI issue on the server it self..? is there any other way to achieve these status..? like IPC or Sockets..? please help..!

Hash.

```
try
{
    agentserviceName = "SQLSERVERAGENT";
    serviceName = "MSSQLSERVER";
    query = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format("select name, startname, State, StartMode from Win32_Service where name = '{0}'", serviceName));
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + srvName + "\\root\\cimv2");
    //ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\ST0176V\\root\\cimv2");
    scope.Connect();
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    // MessageBox.Show((String)dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
    {
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = service["startname"];
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[4].Tag = serviceName;
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = "Currently : " + service["State"] + " - Set As : " + service["StartMode"];
    }

    if (searcher.Get().Count == 0)
    {
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "NO SQL Service Found";
    }

    searcher.Dispose();

    ManagementScope scope2 = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + srvName + "\\root\\cimv2");

    // ObjectQuery query2 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE NAME LIKE '" + serviceName.ToString().ToUpper() + "'");

    System.Management.SelectQuery query2 = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format("select name, startname, State, StartMode from Win32_Service where name like '{0}'", agentserviceName));
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope2, query2);
    foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher1.Get()) // <---- this line throws exception for invalid query, and it is always 2 servers which does that, rest of servers returns proper results. the servers which throws this Invlid Query exceptions are Windows 2000 Server with SP4.
    {
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = service["startname"];
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[6].Tag = agentserviceName;
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = "Currently : " + service["State"] + " - Set As : " + service["StartMode"];
    }
    searcher1.Dispose();        
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to tell us specifically what line is throwing the `Exception` and with what data.  Is it the call to `searcher1.Get()` in the `foreach` block?  Is it always the same servers that fail?

Comment: Thank you BACON, sorry about missing the details.. I have added the comment to the code on which line it throws error, these servers which throws errors are windows 2000 server with SP4, the line which throws excpetion is foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher1.Get()) , the Data in this should be StartName, State and StartMode for this Service.

Comment: It looks like you're just running the exact same query twice only filtering on a different service name, so I can't imagine why one works but the other doesn't.  I do notice that you're calling `scope.Connect()` but not `scope2.Connect()`, though it does say in the documentation for the `Connect` method "This method is called implicitly when the scope is used in an operation that requires it to be connected."  Maybe Windows 2000 doesn't like the two simultaneous scope connections?  Try inserting `scope2.Connect()` before your second `foreach` block and see if it instead fails on that line.

Comment: :-), I did that, thinking, server may be limiting two connection with one scope, thats why I did scope2.connect(), but not luck, windows server 2000 seems to be only allowing one query only, some how I guess I need to kill the scope.connect(), so I can open a new query all over again in second search, but since scope does not have any Dispose() method, I am not sure how to kill it. any idea..?

Comment: Since your two `Scope` objects are constructed using the same path, try getting rid of `scope2` altogether and passing `scope` to the constructor for `searcher1`: `System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query2);`

Comment: yes sir..!.. initial code had scope for both services I am searching. I changed it as you have suggested with (scope, Query2), its same exception, invalid query.. some how I need to KILL the scope or disconnect the session from server i am trying to query, if that is possible somehow, I guess, second part can work as fresh connection...

Answer (score 3):

Since, as we've been discussing in the comments, we're thinking it might have to do with having multiple active `ManagementScope` objects, try changing the first half of your code to this:

```
string agentserviceName = "SQLSERVERAGENT";
string serviceName = "MSSQLSERVER";
// Let the SelectQuery class build our WQL query text...
string className = "Win32_Service";
string condition = string.Format("Name = '{0}'", serviceName);
string[] selectedProperties = new string[] { "Name", "StartName", "State", "StartMode" };
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(className, condition, selectedProperties);

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    searcher.Scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + srvName + "\\root\\cimv2");

    foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
    {
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = service["startname"];
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[4].Tag = serviceName;
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = "Currently : " + service["State"] + " - Set As : " + service["StartMode"];
    }

    if (searcher.Get().Count == 0)
    {
        dgv_ChangeSvcAccount.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "NO SQL Service Found";
    }
}

// Second query goes here...
```

That will dispose the `ManagementObjectSearcher` for the first query when it's done being used, and also ensure that it holds the only reference to the `ManagementScope` for the remote server.

Comment: Bravo..!!!! Bravo..! this works great.. this is perfect solution.! Very well thought..! I could'nt have figured out this way..! Thnak you once again..! this solution is done..! Just a Quick Qestion, instead of WMI, is there any other way I can query service status using IPC or Sockets..? any examples sites..? why I am asking is, on many other servers, we have, does have WMI broken, or RPC Services are broken, not sure how to get to them without using WMI..! anyway.. ! thank you for your reply on this matter...!

Comment: You could do it by P/Invoking the [Win32 API for services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms685974.aspx).  Just quickly browsing the documentation it looks like the [OpenSCManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684323.aspx), [OpenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684330.aspx), and [QueryServiceStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684941.aspx) functions might get you there.  But I've never done that before (through P/Invoke or C) and you should open a new question for that.

Comment: Thank you BACON..! I will try to get my hands dirty first on your suggestions. thank you very much..! have a great time..!

Comment: No problem.  It was an interesting problem to solve.  I'm surprised my code changes fixed it, actually, because I figured it would still potentially leave that `ManagementScope` connected when the second query was executed.  If my answer solved your problem, though, you should accept it as the answer to your question.